# How do I add a column for uri link to external resource(cloudinary assets), to a graphQL - Apollo - Prisma Server for React Native App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, prisma-graphql

I am building a React Native Mock Craft Beer App.

The datamodel.prisma is:

```
Type Beer {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  abv: Int!
  body: String!
  description: String!
  postedBy: User
  votes: [Vote!]!
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt  
}
```

The schema.graphql is:

```
type Beer {
  id: ID! 
  name: String!
  abv: Int!
  body: String!
  votes: [Vote!]!
  postedBy: User
  createdAt: DateTime!
  description: String!
}
```

I would like to add a new field "img:" that would contain the uri for my image assets in Cloudinary.  This will allow me to render images of craft beer in a React Native Carousel component.

This is my first time implementing a graphQL API with a Prisma server.  Coming from a Rails background, I am looking to implement "migrations". However, in the Prisma docs, it states that migrations are still in "experimental" state:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-migrate#supported-operations

There must be a better way to add a field.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide it the field with a default value & you're good to go. For eg: you want to add an `img` field, do it this way:

```
Type Beer {
  img: String!  @default(value: "")
}
```

Comment: Is this Just for the data.model Or do I also have to add this code manually to the graphQL Schema file?  and update the resolvers?

Comment: If you want to. It depends on you whether the image is required for the upcoming documents (records)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the img field into the schema, you also need to update the DB,  do the following command in your terminal

```
 $prisma deploy
```

Comment: Which folder do I run the "deploy" script in?  I'm currently getting  "-bash: deploy: command not found"  when I try to deploy from the "server" folder

Comment: try prisma deploy